# Chrome, Firefox and Edge loose content when going back in browser history

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge

In a `fieldset` I have 5 static `textarea`'s + 2 more `input`'s and a button underneath which generates one line after the other via JavaScript. The texareas and inputs are embedded in a form and will be submitted by another button which is not in the screenshots. HTML code looks like this:

```
<form id="invoice" method="post" action="index.php" > 
  <fieldset><legend>Service</legend>
    <label id="item_header">Item</label>        
    <label id="price_header">Price</label> 

    <label>1</label> 
    <textarea form="invoice"  rows="1" name="item[]" /></textarea>
    <input type="text" name="fee_1[]"  value="" />
    <input type="text" name="fee_2[]"  value="" />
    <br>
    <label>2</label> 
    <textarea form="invoice" rows="1" name="item[]" /></textarea>
    <input type="text" name="fee_1[]"  value=""/>
    <input type="text" name="fee_2[]"  value=""/>
    <br>
    <label>3</label> 
    .......
  </fieldset>
  <input class="button" type="button" value="add line" onclick="addLine()">
   .......
  <input type="submit" value="next page" /> 
</form>
```

Finally it looks like this screenshot 1.

[image: screenshot 1]

After adding some lines it looks like this screenshot 2.

[image: screenshot 2]

When I hit the submit button (which you do not see here) the content is transmitted via `post` method to the server. It works perfect so far.

Sometimes I need to go back to the previous site and add some more item or correct some words. For this I use a `back` link which looks like this

```
<a onclick="history.go(-1)" >Back</a>
```

Now here is an issue where I have a question for.
When I have the set with 5 textareas and inputs and I go back I see all 5 textareas and inputs and all content. So to say it is perfectly restored.

But when I have one ore more dynamic generated textareas and inputs they are lost when I go back in history. But this is `only true` when I use Chrome, FireFox or Edge (all new versions). When I use Safari on a Mac I `get the complete range` restored incl. its content.

The JavaScript code for generating dynamic textareas and inputs looks like this

```
function addLine() {
    var button = document.getElementById('addline_button');
    var list = document.getElementById('items');
    var i = list.getElementsByTagName("label").length-1;

    var n = document.createElement('label');
    n.className='item_label';   
    n.innerHTML = i++ ;
    list.appendChild(n);

    n = document.createElement('textarea');
    n.formname='invoice';   
    n.name='item[]';
    n.rows=1;
    list.appendChild(n);

    n = document.createElement('input');
    n.type='text';  
    n.name="fee_1[]";
    list.appendChild(n);

    n = document.createElement('input');
    n.type='text';  
    n.name="fee_2[]";
    list.appendChild(n);
}
```

Do I miss something in the Javascript that Chrome, Firefox and Edge looses the additional textareas and inputs?
And if so why does Safari shows all content?

Comment: I suggest using `<button onclick>Back</button>` instead of `<a onclick>Back</a>`. That being said, have you compared your cache settings between the browsers? Are you using local storage to store values or just hoping the browser doesn't dump the cache?

Comment: When this is a caching issue then why does Google & co not cache content which is generated dynamically with JS clientside ?

Comment: Settings? Either way, relying on the back button to restore the state of a page is a brittle model. Consider writing state information, values, etc. to local storage so you can restore it regardless of browser settings/quirks.

Comment: Sorry you do not answer my question but I got your message anyway.